# find a,b,c,d of $p(x)=x^{6}-6x^{5}+ax^{4}+bx^{3}+cx^{2}+dx+1$ if p has all only positive roots.

Tags: calculus, inequality

Apparently this a AM-GM question. So one idea is:

$-7(6abcdx^{21})^{7} \leq p(x)\leq (x-\frac{r_{1}+...+r_{6}}{6})^{6}$

To somehow squeeze p(x) between the same polynomial and then equate coefficients.
any hints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vieta's relations for the coefficients you are given tell you that the sum of the roots is $6$ and the product of the roots is $1$. That gives you data for $AM-GM$ (which applies if roots are all positive).

You should be able to take it from there.

Comment: @TKM You can't apply the rational root theorem, because you don't know the roots are rational, only that they are positive. As a matter of interest what values did you get for the $AM$ and $GM$ of the roots?

Comment: only lower bounds: $15\leq a$,$20\leq b$,$15\leq c$,$6\leq d$

Comment: actually, that is enough.

Comment: @TKM The equation has six roots whose sum is $6$ and whose product is $1$. $AM=\frac 66$, $GM=1^{\frac 16}$ - sorry if it wasn't obvious what I meant.

Comment: yes,I used that to find the lower bounds.

Comment: @TKM For future reference - if $AM=GM$ the condition for equality is that all the roots are the same.